# Comparing the influence of $X$ and $Y$ on posterior $q_{_{Z|X,Y}}(\cdot|X,Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, information-theory, bayesian

**Edit:** It appears that this post may not be rendering correctly for some users. A screenshot of how it renders in my browser (Google Chrome) is found below, at the very end of my post.

---

Hello and apologies if this is a basic question (I am very new to information theory).

Suppose that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are discrete random variables with joint probability mass function, $p_{_{XYZ}}$ that has full support on $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}\times\mathcal{Z}$, for some finite sets $\mathcal{X}$, $\mathcal{Y}$, and $\mathcal{Z}$.
Consider a Bayesian agent who has a prior belief $p_{_{XYZ}}$ over $(X,Y,Z)$. After observing the realization $(x,y)$ of $(X,Y)$ -- but *not* the realization of $Z$ -- the agent forms a posterior belief $q_{_{Z|XY}}(\cdot|x,y)$ about $Z$ using Bayes' rule, i.e.
$$
q_{_{Z|XY}}(z|x,y) = \frac{p_{_{XYZ}}(x,y,z)}{\sum\limits_{\tilde{x}\in\mathcal{X}}\sum\limits_{\tilde{y}\in\mathcal{Y}} p_{_{XYZ}}(\tilde{x},\tilde{y},z)},\quad \forall (x,y,z)\in\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}\times \mathcal{Z}.
$$

**My question:** Is there a precise, mathematical way to compare the relative influence of $X$ and $Y$ on the agent's posterior beliefs? That is, I am interested in saying the following in a precise, (rigorous, mathematically formal, etc.) way:

> "Given realization $(x,y)$ of $(X,Y)$, $X$ had more influence on the agent's posterior beliefs than did $Y$"

It would be even better if there is a way to make a *cardinal* statement like

> "Given realization $(x,y)$ of $(X,Y)$, $X$ had $\alpha\%$ more influence on the agent's posterior beliefs than did $Y$"

Are there any commonly used/standard notions of either of the above? Apologies that this question is not fully precise (I usually try to make sure I am being as precise as possible). But indeed, my question is essentially on how to make either of the above statements fully precise.

---

$$ \mathbf{Screenshot\ of\ my\ post} $$

[image: Screenshot of correctly rendered question]

---

Comment: Please fixe your TeX symbols.

Comment: Apologies. Where are the errors? I am looking over what I wrote and I cannot seem to find any.

Comment: I really have been looking over it, and I really cannot seem to find anything amiss! Sorry for the inconvenience, David; please let me know if it still does not look right to you.

Comment: What do your boxes represent?

Comment: Ah, I see: it seems that my post is not rendering the same way on your end as it is on mine. I checked in another browser where I was not logged in, and it still seems to be rendering correctly (‍♂️). 

I posted a screenshot above! Apologies again for the inconvenience, David, and thank you for letting me know.